# NSMutableDictionary にオブジェクトを値で保存したい

Tags: objective-c

配列の値の遷移を保存しておきたいと思い、下の例のようなプログラムを作成しました。

```
NSMutableDictionary*  historyDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:@"1"];
[historyDic setObject:array forKey:@"First"];

[array addObject:@"2"];
[historyDic setObject:array forKey:@"Second"];

[array addObject:@"3"];
[historyDic setObject:array forKey:@"Third"];

NSLog(@"First ->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"First"]);
NSLog(@"Second->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"Second"]);
NSLog(@"Third ->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"Third"]);
```

しかし、このように辞書に途中途中でオブジェクトを保存しても参照として保存されるのでどのキーのオブジェクトも読み出し時の状態になってしまっています。

実行結果：

```
First -> (1,2,3)
Second-> (1,2,3)
Third -> (1,2,3)
```

期待した結果：

```
First -> (1)
Second-> (1,2)
Third -> (1,2,3)
```

NSMutableDictionaryに参照ではなく、値としてオブジェクトを保存する方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

値を保存することはできませんが、`[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array]`でNSMutableArrayのコピーの参照を保存することができます。

```
NSMutableDictionary*  historyDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:@"1"];
[historyDic setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array] forKey:@"First"];

[array addObject:@"2"];
[historyDic setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array] forKey:@"Second"];

[array addObject:@"3"];
[historyDic setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array] forKey:@"Third"];

NSLog(@"First ->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"First"]);
NSLog(@"Second->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"Second"]);
NSLog(@"Third ->%@" , [historyDic objectForKey:@"Third"]);
```

Comment: なるほど、コピーの参照を保存すればそれ以降は影響されませんね。ただ一点教えてください。[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array] は [NSArray arrayWithArray:array] としてはダメですか？

Comment: 保存したいのが`NSArray`なら`[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]`でOKです。

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *historyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:@"1"];
[histroyArray addObject [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];

[array addObject:@"2"];
[histroyArray addObject [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];

[array addObject:@"3"];
[histroyArray addObject [NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];

NSUInteger history = 0;
for (NSData *past in historyArray) {
    NSLog(@"%ld -> %@", ++history, [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:past]);
```

とすると、どんなデータ型にも使えますね